# Passing a datatable to .net method using X++

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I have a requirement to send the data using X++ to .net method which accepts a datatable as parameter and returns a List.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .NET classes natively from X++. This code is pasted from a real method I have in production:

```
public static container DataSet2Con(System.Data.DataSet _dataSet)
{
    System.Data.DataTableCollection     dataTableCol;
    System.Data.DataTable               dataTable;
    System.Data.DataRowCollection       dataRowCol;
    System.Data.DataRow                 dataRow;
    int                                 dataRowCount;
    System.Data.DataColumnCollection    dataColCol;
    System.Data.DataColumn              dataCol;
    int                                 dataColCount;

    ...

    dataTableCol    = _dataSet.get_Tables();
    dataTable       = dataTableCol.get_Item(0);
    dataRowCol      = dataTable.get_Rows();
    dataRowCount    = dataRowCol.get_Count();
    dataColCol      = dataTable.get_Columns();
    dataColCount    = dataColCol.get_Count();

    for (c = 0; c < dataColCount; c++)
    {
        dataCol = dataColCol.get_Item(c);
        straux = dataCol.get_ColumnName();
        ...
    }
    ...
```